# Github workflow: requested access to the resource is denied

Tags: docker, github, dockerfile, github-actions, docker-image

I am trying to use GitHub workflow to build an ASP.NET 6 project using `Dockerfile` then push the image to a private Azure Registry using docker.

Here is my `.yml` file

```
name: Docker Image CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Login To Azure Container Registr 
      uses: Azure/docker-login@v1 
      with:
        login-server: ${{ secrets.ACR_HOST }}
        username: ${{ secrets.ACR_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.ACR_PASSWWORD }} 
    - name: Build And Push Docker Images
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v3.1.1
      with:
        push: true
        file: ./Dockerfile
        tags: companyname/projectname:${{ github.run_number }}
```

In the above, the `Dockerfile` is located in the root of my project's code.

However, the the build runs I get the following error

> *Error:* buildx failed with: error: denied: requested access to the resource is denied

In the `Secrets > Action` section in my repository settings, I added `ACR_HOST`, `ACR_USERNAME` and `ACR_PASSWORD` secrets.

When viewing the logs, this issue seems to happen after this line in the logs

```
pushing companyname/projectname:2 with docker:
```

How can I solve this issue?

**UPDATED**

I changed the `.yml` script to the following

```
name: Docker Image CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Login To Azure Container Registr 
      uses: Azure/docker-login@v1 
      with:
        login-server: mycontainer.azurecr.io
        username: "The admin username"
        password: "The admin password"

    - run: cat ${{ env.DOCKER_CONFIG }}/config.json

    - name: Build And Push Docker Images
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v3.1.1
      with:
        push: true
        file: ./Dockerfile
        tags: companyname/projectname:${{ github.run_number }}
```

The added step (i.e., `cat ${{ env.DOCKER_CONFIG }}/config.json`) displayed a json string that look like this

```
{"auths":{"mycontainer.azurecr.io":{"auth":"BASE64 string with the admin username:password as expected"}}}
```

The base64 string was formatted like this `username:password`

I am assuming that the step `Azure/docker-login@v1` has no issue and stages the token for `docker/build-push-action@v3.1.1` correctly.

If I set the `push` flag to false in the `docker/build-push-action@v3.1.1` step, the workflow runs with no issue. So from what I can tell, the issue is when the step `docker/build-push-action@v3.1.1` tries to push the created image to the Azure registry.

I use my local machine to login using the same credentials  and all worked with no issue `docker login mycontainer.azurecr.io`

Additionally, the login request from my local machine is logged into Azure portal. However, I do not see the request when I run the workflow.

I think that main issue is that the step `docker/build-push-action@v3.1.1` does not attempt to login before it pushes the image.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions [here](https://axellarsson.com/blog/github-actions-build-docker-image-and-push-to-private-registry/) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Incase it didn't work with the above method, change the password in the github secrets with the token from the docker account.

**Steps:**

1. Go to account settings
2. Go to security
3. Click on New  Access Token
4. Once token is generated, paste it in the github secrets with keyname of your choice
5. Now use the same key as password for login action in the workflow file